# Python won't show text when using print() function

Tags: python, printing

I am experimenting with pdfminer. I have found a code snippet, which I wanted to try out before further examination. The goal of this code is to extract text from a .pdf and store it in an str object. It works nicely, it extracts the text from the pdf document, the problem comes when I try to print the str. It prints nothing.

The str does contain the text, I can print parts of it with `print(text[0:10])` for example. It will also print the whole thing using `print(text[0:len(s)-1])` I can also write it to a file without any problems.

Only the `print()` function doesn't work on its own. It is a standard str with utf-8 encoding.

I get the same result when I write the content of the .pdf into a bytes object, and then I convert it to an str. Although python can print the bytes object without any problems.

It is not an IDE problem as well, I get the same result both in Spyder and in VS Code.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Here is the code I use (if I try to print the variable s, nothing happens):

```html
import io

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = extract_text_from_pdf('mypdf.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: this code works correctly.

Not sure how to help you.
What is the error message you get?
What is the file size of your .pdf?
Does process finish with exit code 0?
Does the process never finish and you have to terminate?

I put your code in PyCharm and ran it on a 'complex' pdf and a 'simple' pdf.
(The only step I had to take prior to running it was to ensure pdfminer was installed, which I'm assuming you also did.)

- The 'complex' pdf took a very long time (24 pages with graphics, etc.). Windows Task Manager assured me it was running.
- The 'simple' pdf took seconds.

Some print statements confirm each page is 'got':

```
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            print(type(page))
            print(page)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I don't get anything, no error. It exits with an error 0, so it runs and finishes correctly. The reason I was asking was, that I confirmed that the string variable contains the output, but I wasn't able to print it to the console. I was just wondering what I am missing here.

If it works for you, the problem is not in the code, I will experiment on the environment then.

Btw, I tried it with a simple pdf file. Just a few lines. Pdfminer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Bit too late I imagine, but in the hope it helps someone else:

I had a similar problem, could print using slices of the string, but nothing would show up on the screen. I printed the whole string successfully with print(text[-1]). So the problem was the final character.

Used ord(text[-1]) to find the ASCII code of the last character. Turns out it is a printer command for Form Feed. I guess this messed up the printing to screen.